# Top Questions page shows "-1 Votes"

Tags: bug

I don't much like the new look of the Top Questions page. Too much whitespace, IMHO.

But one rather silly piece is the "Votes" indicator. It doesn't display the *count* of votes as I would expect and as we do with "Views" and "Answers", but rather the *net score* of votes.

Thus we see the odd "-1 Votes".

My suggestion: either display the number of votes cast, or change the term to "Score" rather than "Votes".

Comment: Pro tip: Don't click on "home" click on Questions. That way you don't get that odd layout

Comment: @DarkCygnus - thanks, but the Active Questions page still shows "-1 votes". Hurts my QA eyes, but I guess I'll have to live with it.

Comment: Oh, I see... I guess that I don't see those because I mostly watch the "Newest" tab, not the Active one

Comment: There’s [a feature request to change ‘votes’ to ‘score’](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153515/273494) from 9 years ago that was recently marked [status-review], so there is a tiny glimmer of hope. I [keep nagging them about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el#comment1249640_375081), but I’m not sure if it is helping.

Comment: Just FYI [Votes will be changed to Score. Answers are currently sorted based on the score (upvotes - downvotes), not the number of votes (upvotes+downvotes). This language makes that distinction clearer, and is a long-asked-for change that we are delivering.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375749/273494)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is something that's being rolled out [network wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el) and as you can see from the answers to the post on main meta you aren't the only one who doesn't like the new layout.

Personally, I'm decidedly **not** a fan either :(

Comment: Oh well. Just one more thing in the "don't like" column. I guess I'll learn to live with it.